# How to detect if a certain file has been changed on the current git branch

Tags: git, continuous-integration

I'm trying to detect if a certain file has been changed on the current feature branch of my repo from within my CI.

My current approach is to use `git --no-pager diff @~..@ -- PATH_TO_FILE`, but this apparently only outputs changes for the last commit, not if the change occurred in a previous commit on this branch.

Is it possible to specify such a range?

Comment: Well, you are specifying `@~..@` which means "from the previous commit to the current one". You can certainly open it up a lot by using different commits. Also, you can just use `--name-only` so that only the file is listed if changed, so that you do not get a diff output, which I don't thing you need.

Comment: You'll need to define what you mean by "a file has changed on the current branch", because files don't change *on branches* in the first place. Each commit holds  a full snapshot of *all* files, and "change" means "different in commit X vs commit Y" so you must pick two commits X and Y. But "changed on branch" could mean "has ever changed in any historical commit reached from the branch tip", or "has changed in a particular set of commits reached from the branch tip". What if commit a12345 changes file F, commit b5678 changes it again, and final commit c9abc changes it back to the original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't named any specific service, but I will assume that you are using `github` or `gitlab` or `Azure devops` or ... and that you work with Pull Requestst (or Merge Requests), and that the events that trigger your CI are based on this.

---

The PR that triggered your CI job indicates that the `<feature>` branch should be merged to a specific `<master branch>` (can be `master`, `main`, `develop`, `ci` ...).

You can see the diff of your feature branch using the [3 dots notation for git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203-1) :

```
git diff <master branch>...<feature>
```

this will show you the changes that landed on `feature` since it forked from `<master branch>`.
You can add any other regular `git diff` options:

```
git diff --name-only <master branch>...<feature>
git diff --name-status  <master branch>...<feature>
git diff <master branch>...<feature> -- path/to/file
# etc ...
```

Check the doc of your CI tool to see how you can get the target branch of your PR.